# Jquery DataTable Reinitialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am reading data from google spreadsheet from multiple sheets and displaying the retrieved data in the tabular format. I am creating table rows having data in an ajax call once data is retrieved i.e.

```
$tbody.append('<tr><td>'+rows[i][6]+'</td>'+'<td>'+rows[i][0]+'</td><td>'+rows[i][1]+'</td><td>'+rows[i][2]+'</td><td>'+rows[i][3]+'</td><td>'+rows[i][4]+'</td><td>'+rows[i][5]+'</td><td><a id="UpdateLink" href="#">Update</a></tr>');
```

On the very first run the data appears fine but when I happen to have data from another sheet I see no paging is applied and when I click any header column to perform the sort It displays data from the first sheet.

Upon google It was suggested to use destroy attribute for datatable i.e. 
$("#spreadsheetdata).DataTable({
destroy:true
});
but behavior remains the same.
I have also applied

```
if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#spreadsheetdata' ) ) {
        //dataTableInstance = $('#spreadsheetdata').DataTable();
    }
    else {
        dataTableInstance = $('#spreadsheetdata').DataTable( {
            paging:true,
            ordering:true,
            info:true
        });
    }
```

but no desirable results.
please guide thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather adding the rows with the jQuery append method, you'll need to use the DataTables [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) method.

If `dataTableInstance` is the variable you're assigning to your table and `rows` is the array of data from your Google spreadsheet, this syntax should allow you to append new rows to an existing table:

```
dataTableInstance.row.add([
  rows[i][6],
  rows[i][0],
  rows[i][1],
  rows[i][2],
  rows[i][3],
  rows[i][4],
  rows[i][5],
  '<a id="UpdateLink" href="#">Update</a>'
]).draw();
```

The reason appending the new rows with jQuery doesn't work is that DataTables maintains its own client-side state -- see [`search()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()), [`order()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/order()), and [`page()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) for examples.

So, if you add rows directly to the table body, they'll disappear as soon as you sort, search, etc.